# How can I get the "Would You Kindly..." achievement?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

The "Would You Kindly..." achievement in Starcraft 2 states:

> Destroy 5 units with a single Neural Parasited unit in an Unranked or Ranked game.

Since the achievement was introduced, Neural Parasite's range has been reduced and opponents have gotten better at targeting infesters. You also can no longer earn the Unranked/Ranked achievements in Free-For-All like at the launch of Wings of Liberty, so a number of the tricks people used to recommend don't work anymore.  I also struggle to kill five units before the duration expires.

What can I do to get this achievement?  It's the only one I'm missing for Supreme Being.

Comment: Obvious choice of a way to kill five units is a Ghost with a Nuke (you can use enemies' own Nukes). Now how to obtain a Ghost... I don't know if you can NP an allied unit, that would be an easy way.

Comment: It seem you can't :-(

Answer (score 3):

You want to control an AoE (area of effect) unit. A quite common is tanks from the Terran race. Their splash damage is enough to kill either a pack of zerglings or marines rather swiftly. A Helion can also do the trick vs zergling, even better if it has blue-flame upgrade. Tho this is fragile and thus you need to kite the zergligs with it.

You do at least want high ground, meaning you'd want to scout around the opponent(s) base(s) to see when the push out with something you can use. IF the trick still works (been a little while since I played, so not 100% up to date on stuff), you can launch the parasite and burrow at the same time, making your infestor able to stay hidden as the unit moves about.

Good AoE units to look for per race:

- Terran: Tank and Thor
- Protos: High templar and Colossus
- Zerg: Ultralisk

Keep in mind it's only 1 unit, so you want something that can take a pounding as well as deliver, hence helion is really pointless unless there is an enemy zerg on the field as well with lings. Ghosts are no-go. Yes they can drop nukes, but only if one is made, and it's uncertain. The listed units are sure to do the job if used properly. There might be a unit or two I've forgotten, but consider the list the more likely units for you to see.

*If possible, what you can do, if you want to cheese it, is to have a friend play something like terran, and you gain control over their tank, before he sends in a small pack of marines for the tank to destroy. However this method may not be viable for this achievement.*

Comment: The cheesing part is tough because it has to be a ranked/unranked ladder game and you can't parasite your allies.  Custom and FFA don't work.

Comment: Then I didn't remember correct. I was thinking more of going ranked\unranked matchmaking, where your friend was on another team. But I guess that would go as custom and thus not work as you said.

Comment: Protoss Archons might be a viable target for control too

Comment: Archons don't do enough AoE (if any at all, I think they do, but very little) and aren't fast enough to legitimately kill 5 Zerglings, let alone Protoss units. Playing vs. Protoss, High Templars might be your only real shot and you probably need to have put some damage on the units you're aiming to kill already, a single Psi Storm isn't enough to kill any Protoss unit.

Comment: Psi storm can kill the probes if they are stacked up. It deals 80 damage over 4 seconds, that's 20 damage per tick. A probe has 40 "life" if you include shield in that stat, meaning it would need 2 ticks to kill them. A well placed storm would kill most basic units within those 4 seconds.